# Testing ScrollIntoView in Jest

Tags: jestjs

With the function which uses scrollIntoView

```
export const scrollDown = () => {
    document.querySelector('.bottom').scrollIntoView({ 
        behavior: 'smooth' 
    });
}
```

I have a test here that goes like this

```
describe('scrollDown', () => {
    let scrollIntoViewMock = jest.fn();
    window.HTMLElement.prototype.scrollIntoView = scrollIntoViewMock;
    scrollDown()
    expect(scrollIntoViewMock).toBeCalled();
})
```

But the test is failing with the TypeError: Cannot set property 'scrollIntoView' of undefined

The test was from another SO answer for scrollIntoView testing question. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add an `HTMLElement` with class `bottom` to the `document`:

```js
const scrollDown = () => {
  document.querySelector('.bottom').scrollIntoView({ 
      behavior: 'smooth' 
  });
}

test('scrollDown', () => {
  document.body.innerHTML = '<div class="bottom"></div>';
  const scrollIntoViewMock = jest.fn();
  HTMLElement.prototype.scrollIntoView = scrollIntoViewMock;
  scrollDown();
  expect(scrollIntoViewMock).toBeCalledWith({ behavior: 'smooth' });  // Success!
})
```